# How to fix Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in Xcode 7 swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am working on core data and when I start the app and click on a button to go to the next page it crashes and gives me this error. I'm not sure how to fix it.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: **'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'Item''**

```
func saveItem(item: String) {
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

  let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
  let Item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

  Item.setValue(item, forKey: "name")
  var error: NSError?
  do {
    try managedContext.save()
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
  Items.append(Item)
}

func fetchData() {
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

  var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
  var error: NSError?
  do {
    let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: **Read the error carefully**. If you still don't get it, post the faulty code so that we can inspect it.

Comment: do you have any more detail?

Comment: @GetanehKudna: Please add the code to your question with proper formatting.

Comment: @GetanehKudna: Where are you loading your CoreData model?

Comment: @GetanehKudna: You have a CoreData model file, where you have an entity named `Item`. To be able to use this entity, you need to load the model file first.

Comment: I have a model file thats where I named the Entities "Item" and the Attributes "name".

Answer (score -1):

Select the `.xcdatamodeld` file.

[image]

Comment: Its the same as the Entities and it still gives me an error Warif Akhand Rishi

Comment: did you try delete the app and make a fresh build?

Comment: yes and it still says NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'Item''

Comment: okay I fix parts of it now but I still have some error. I deleted this part ->v  let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]